# Mapping Control+Command+Eject on non-apple keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

How would I map different key combinations using Eject, such as Control+Command+Eject that restarts computer, when using non-Apple keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eject key combinations are pretty much hardwired into the Mac, there's no way to swap the key without perhaps [untested] using something like [Karabiner-Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org)

What you *can* do quite easily is map any key combo of your choice to the Restart or Shut Down menu commands, with one slight caveat.

[image]

Note here we have a key combo for `Shut Down…` with the ellipsis that normally appears in the menu.
The slight oddity is that once you add this as a key commend, it works perfectly well, but the Mac automatically adds another `Shut Down` command to the menu bar, without the ellipsis. I don't know why it does this. It also does it to Restart… if you set a key command for that too.
This does mean that if you want it to shut down or restart without the dialog, you have to add a *second* command to the new menu item.

[image]